# Regular expression for formal languages

Tags: regex, formal-languages

I'm trying to write a regular expression for a language consisting of:

- Strings which contain any number of a’s followed by a single b and
- Strings which contain any number of a’s followed by a single b followed by an even number of a's.

I thought `(b | ((a^+)b)^* ) U (a | ( (b^+) a)* )` but it was wrong.

Is there anyone who knows where am I wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Assumption**

I'll assume it should be `"strings that consist of"`, not `"strings which contains"`. The difference is that `bbbbbaaabaabbbb` would be a valid string if it's `"contains"` (since it contains `aaabaa`).

To make it `"strings that contains"`, the only difference would be adding `.*?` to the start and `.*` to the end (or `[ab]*?` and `[ab]*` if you want to limit it to `a` and `b`).

**Problem analysis**

I believe you can simplify the problem to just `"strings that consist of any number of a's followed by a single b followed by an even number of a's"`, since 0 is an even number.

I have no idea what `^` or `U` is doing in your regular expression. Is this language specific syntax (usually `^` indicates the start of the line / string)?

**Solution**

It should be as simple as:

```
a*b(aa)*
```

`a*` - any number of a's
`b` - a single b
`(aa)*` an even number of a's

**EDIT:**

According to comments, it appears that you may want strings that consist of something like:

- any number of a's
- followed by any number of the following:

  - a single b
  - followed by an even number of a's (number != 0)
- optionally followed by a b

The regex would be:

```
a*(b(aa)+)*b?
```

Comment: ıt doesnt provide a string like aaaabaaaab

Comment: @caesar_ But that doesn't fit into `"strings which contain any number of a's followed by a single b followed by an even number of a's"` (since there's a `b` at the end). Oh wait, is it "strings that consists of ..." or "strings that contain ..."?

Comment: Yea you're right but, i also need to provide these kind of example. I mean aaaabaaaab or aaaaabaabaabaaaa , do you have any idea ?

Comment: it is contain not consists of .